# Iteration via expandable nested 'for' loops without itertools

Tags: python, for-loop, ascii, nested-loops, python-itertools

I am trying to make a list of iterations of the alphabet with itself to the `n`-th power but I am unable to find an appropriate way of achieving this. I would rather not use `itertools` for the time being.

My idea is as follows, although I lack the ingenuity to turn it into code that would yield, for instance, `['A', 'B', ..., 'Z']` for `n = 0`, `['AA', 'AB', ..., 'ZZ']` for `n = 1`, and so on, where `n` is the power of the self-iteration:

```
import string

a = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

aa = []
for i in a:
    for j in a:
        for k in a:
            for l in a:
                ... (n-4 times)
                   aa.append(i + j + k + l + ...)

Desired output: ['AAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAB', ..., 'ZZZZZZZ']
```

I am self-taught, so I may not have come up with the simplest of workarounds or solutions - keep this in mind. I appreciate your inputs in advance. Have a good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using recursivity can do the trick in a very concise manner in your case:

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase

def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [""]
    else:
        return [x + y for x in f(n-1) for y in alphabet ]
```

A call to `f(n)` concatenates all letters to all returned values in `f(n-1)` and return this new list. If `n == 0` you return a list of an empty string.

**Output:**

```
f(3)
```

gives

```
['AAA',
 'AAB',
 'AAC',
 'AAD',
 'AAE',
 'AAF',
 'AAG',
 'AAH',
 'AAI',
 'AAJ',
 'AAK',
 'AAL',
 'AAM',
 ...
```